# Minimalist electric guitar setup

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, amplifiers

I have an electric guitar. My combo amp (really basic one) broke down yesterday.

I'm looking for an alternative but, this time, i would live to find a small  device on which I can plug both my guitar and my headsets.
But, I still need a very good sound with the ability to load presets.

PS : I found that VOX amPlug 2 but it's limited as you have to buy one for each music genre. So if I take the metal one, then I couldn't have the clean mode.

Does it exist ?

Comment: Any small multi-effects unit with a headphone socket should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
So multi effects act like an amplifier ?

Comment: They act like a preamplifier, and if they have a headphone socket, they also act like a headphone amplifier. So, just as an example, you could use something like a [Zoom G1on](https://www.zoom.co.jp/products/guitar/zoom-g1on-guitar-multi-effects-processor) with some headphones, and you wouldn't need anything else.

Comment: BTW I am assuming that you want to use normal headphones with a standard stereo audio jack - not 'headsets' with a USB connection or 4-contact jack, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I own a few practice amps/devices including the amPlug, orange crush and line 6 amplifi.

They are all fine, but it depends on how YOU like to practice. Opinions aside, if you want to hear yourself play and you don't have any space and no budget, then the amPlugs actually sound good. Like you said, they are limited especially if you're looking for the chug needed for metal. If you always use high gain or distortion when playing, then get this. (I use the AC30 because I like that edge of break up sound)

Next level up is the orange crush 12. Really great amp for the bedroom. It has a headphone out and EQ for treble, mid and bass as well gain and overdrive. If you don't need a speaker, there is an amp called the "Micro Terror" that works great with headphones, but can also connect to a speaker cabinet.

If you are on a tighter budget there is an amp called the Blackstar Fly 3 that some say sounds better than the Orange crush 12 and it has bluetooth so you can play along with your phone.

If you're going for really customizable sounds, then the line 6 amplifi is pretty good. It uses an android or ios app to select the sounds and settings. You can save them to the amp so its stored in memory without having to constantly pair your device. It's like a premium bluetooth speaker like Bose, so might be a little out of range, but figured I'd mention it. Line 6 Pod isn't bad either, but is in the same price range.

Finally, if use a laptop or tablet it might be worth looking in to getting an iRig or other USB connection. I see this as the general direction practicing is going. The upside is that you can record your riffs while practicing so you don't forget.

Obviously there are a ton of products, but I figured I'd mention the ones I've used and general features.

Comment: The Orange Micro Terror now has a little sister called the Micro Dark, aimed at higher gain sounds if I understand correctly. It comes with cabinet simulation for the headphone output, and an effects loop. Seems worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Vox Amplug and while I found it useful for traveling it's not the best at home. About a month ago I bought a Yamaha THR10 amp - small, cheap(ish), will run on batteries   if you want, but a great sound with or without headphones.  They have just released an all-new model so you may find the last of the previous models for bargain prices. I bought the old model just before the new one was announced, but I am really happy with it!